# How to prevent Softmax to be overconfidence/getting stuck in one solution

Tags: neural-networks, softmax

I have a Neural Network (Feed Forward Neural Network) with Softmax as the output. The neural network is maximizing some loss (call it $L$), with respect to the input called VAMP2 (there is not True labels!). The optimization process goes by minimizing the loss as much as possible. The loss is bound by $N$, where $N$ is number of Softmax outputs. So $max\{L\} = N$

The problem is that often Softmax, does maximize the loss only for one or two of its outputs (depending on the random seed). Let's say that the number of outputs $N$ is $N=4$.  Then Softmax optimizes only 2 of the outputs, the other 2 always stay 0 or 1. How to prevent such a scenario ? Are there some tricks with Softmax to prevent it ? It does look like Softmax can't get out of some local minima or get stuck there. Could I use some specific regularization for Softmax ? As Entropy ?

***Loss definition if one would look at it***
$$L = -||C_{00}^{-1/2}C_{01}C_{11}^{-1/2}||^2_F$$
where
$$C_{00}=Cov(\chi_1, \chi_1); C_{01}=Cov(\chi_1, \chi_2); C_{00}=Cov(\chi_2, \chi_2);$$
and $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are outputs of the neural network shifted by time $\tau$. The input and output of the neural network is an ordered time-series. So one can shift it.